# KeyDown Event in c# store only last character which i pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to do like what ever thing is write from keyboard it will store on text file which i created. but it will store only the last key pressed in text file what should i do if store all the thing to the file.

```
private void Window_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"E:\PERSONAL\demo.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path).Dispose();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            sw.WriteAsync(e.Key.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }

    }
    else if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            sw.WriteAsync(e.Key.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;

}
```

Comment: I removed the code from your question that would have nothing to do with your problem

Comment: last key pressed from keyboard it will store in text file, but i have to store all the things which i pressed from keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the constructor of [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will append to the file

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
```

From the documentation for the [constructor you are using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

So what you are finding is every time you capture a keypress - currently it overwrites the file